# DbUpdateConcurrencyException - how to access to data while modifying one of records?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Name,Notes")] Collection collection, int LanguageID)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            collection.Language = db.Languages.Find(LanguageID);
            db.Entry(collection).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(collection);
    }
```

Everytinhg worked until I add this:

```
collection.Language = db.Languages.Find(LanguageID);
```

The error that Visual Studio shows:

> 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

It seems like I can't get any data while modifying one of records in db. But I have to somehow get "Langauge" object to assign it to "Collection" object.

Any ideas what should I change?

Comment: works fine ? are you sure ? you do not seems to have any valued PK for your Collection object.

Comment: Does `collection` have any foreign keys? If it is only `Language` that you are willing to update, you might want to try `db.Entry(collection).Property(c => c.Language).IsModified = true`.